# Objective-c UIScrollView now scrolling nor vertically nor horizontally

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview

I don't understand why my project doesn't work.
I can open the window, but the scrollview wont scroll, which means I can't see the bottom of my UI. Why? I read answers to similar questions but they didn't help me fix my issue.

THIS IS THE DETAILVC.H

```
@interface DetailVC : UIViewController {
IBOutlet UIImageView *iv_main, *iv_ratings;
IBOutlet UITextField *tf_name, *tf_dob, *tf_age, *tf_weight, *tf_height,*tf_birthplace;
IBOutlet UITextView *tv_description;
IBOutlet UIButton *but_movies, *but_edit;
IBOutlet UINavigationBar *navbar;
IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *iv_main, *iv_ratings;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *tf_name, *tf_dob, *tf_age, *tf_weight, *tf_height, *tf_birthplace;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextView *tv_description;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *but_movies, *but_edit;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UINavigationBar *navbar;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
@end
```

THIS IS THE DETAILVC.M

```
 #import "DetailVC.h"

 @interface DetailVC ()

 @end

 @implementation DetailVC

 @synthesize iv_main, iv_ratings, tf_age, tf_birthplace, tf_dob, tf_height, tf_name, tf_weight, tv_description, but_edit, but_movies,navbar, scrollView;

 - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;


}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 1000);

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

------Connection Inspector
http://s18.postimg.org/qjzrdz9a1/Schermata_2013_08_07_alle_16_47_19.png

------Scroll View attributed Inspector
http://s8.postimg.org/5eniaq8r9/Schermata_2013_08_07_alle_17_35_04.png

Comment: Have you ensured userInteraction is enabled and also scrolling enabled

Comment: For some WEIRD reason right now it's workink and i changed just 
THIS
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 1000);
WITH THIS
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 800)];

now... how can i avoid that it shows the bottom view when it scroll up too much? here's a picture to show what i mean

Comment: that's the picture
http://s18.postimg.org/fii3vmf21/image.jpg

Comment: make sure your content inset is set to 0

Comment: also, generally the convention for property names in obj-c is `camelCased`, not `underscore_spaced`. I.e. I would use `mainImageView` not `iv_main` for a property name... just a style point...

Comment: Also, scroll views on iPhone always bounce past the end--are you trying to eliminate that behavior?

Comment: Yes i want to eliminate that behavior, and yes content inset is set to 0

Answer (score 0):

Is there a chance that the frame of your UIScrollView has the same size as contentSize? If yes, the UIScrollView will think it has enough frame to display all of the content.